# Magento: Add relationship between order model and custom module model, with database constraint

Tags: php, object, magento, entity-relationship

I've created a module that has its own table `faces`. Also, the module setup adds a `face_id` attribute sales/order to connect them:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
    CREATE TABLE `{$this->getTable('faces')}` (
      `face_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`face_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
    ");

if (Mage::helper('faces')->isSalesFlat()) { // 1.4
    // TBD
} else { // 1.3
    $eav = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('sales_setup');
    $eav->addAttribute('order', 'face_id', array('type' => 'int'));
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

This is working great in my 1.3.2.4 install. But there are aspects of the relationship between `order` and `face` that I'd like to have. Namely, I'd like to be able to do things like this:

```
$face = $order->getFace(); // This method doesn't exist right now
$faceTitle = $face->getTitle();
```

Also, I'd like to add constraints. I would add them directly to the `CREATE TABLE` SQL, but I'm wondering if they are automatically added if I use some sort of built in method for creating this relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not added automatically. You could choose to store this information on the order table (by modifying it directly to add that column during setup) or you could create a table to join the two (`order_face` basically). The advantage of the former is that it would allow you to pull the data into the order and at least get $order->getFaceId() automatically. With a quick change to the model you could load that face automatically.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the clarification.